# Pergunta da "meia-tigela"

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Se alguma pessoa ou coisa não tem importância ou qualidade, dizemos que é ***de meia-tigela***. A expressão parece estar em uso em todo o mundo lusófono: temos [“políticos de meia tigela”](http://www.portaldeangola.com/2016/10/eua-fazem-ultimato-a-luanda/) em Angola (se fosse só lá!); um autodenominado [Poeta de Meia-Tigela](http://www.recantodasletras.com.br/autor_textos.php?id=153906) no Brasil; um [“escrevinhador de meia-tigela"](http://www.jsn.com.cv/opiniao/1845-casimiro-de-pina-o-up-grade-da-ignorancia-a-imbecilidade-presuncosa.html) em Cabo Verde; [“jornalistas de meia-tigela”](http://macua.blogs.com/moambique_para_todos/2015/04/jornalistas-de-meia-tigela.html) em Moçambique; [“feministas de meia-tigela”](http://porfalarnoutracoisa.sapo.pt/2015/02/feminazi-as-feministas-de-meia-tigela.html) em Portugal (isto começa a ficar deprimente); oh não! e mais um [“político de meia-tigela”](http://www.parvodigital.info/index.php/noticias/politica/item/1205-pcd-propoe-calendarizacao-de-novos-pacotes-legislativos-na-proxima-sessao-legislativa) em São Tomé e Príncipe.

Agora, o que eu quero saber é donde é que isto vem. Encontram-se milhentos sites com explicações; uso documentado ou fontes é que não. Em quase todo o lado se diz que isto vem da fidalguia ou casa real portuguesas. O [Brasil Escola](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/curiosidades/de-meia-tigela.htm) tem uma explicação muito elaborada, segundo a qual se chamaria no Portugal medieval *fidalgos de meia-tigela* aos filhos segundos que não herdavam terras nem participavam num banquete ritual onde se quebrava a loiça. No [Globo.com](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/qual-e-origem-das-expressoes-2.html) diz-se que se chamava *meia-tigela* a funcionares menores da corte, que, de acordo com o “Livro da Cozinha del Rei”, recebiam uma ração inferior. No [Significados](https://www.significados.com.br/meia-tigela/) encontra-se uma explicação diferente, que *meia-tigela* tinha a ver com os escravos que recebia menos comida se trabalhassem menos. O problema é que ninguém explica como é que sabe isto.

Então o que eu procuro é uma explicação da origem, completa ou não, mas devidamente documentada. Nomeadamente,  gostaria de saber quais são, e de quando são, os exemplos mais antigos desta expressão. Aí ficaremos a saber se é *fidalgo, criado ou escravo de meia-tijela*. E gostaria também de saber quando é que se começa a ver a expressão usada fora do contexto original, isto é aplicada a outras personagens, como jornalistas ou políticos.

Comment: É uma expressao que se mapeia bem no ingles ["half assed"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172341/the-origin-of-the-term-half-assed/216911)

Comment: Jacinto, eu diria que a expressão já foi muito usada no Brasil mas que, nos dias de hoje, seu uso anda em queda.  Não tenho ouvido adolescentes e adultos jovens usando-a, o que pode torná-la obsoleta dentro de algumas décadas.

Comment: @Centaurus Parece nao ser muito usada de fato https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=meia%20tigela. Mas ainda dá 489,000 resultados no google

Comment: `banquete ritual onde se quebrava a loiça` ... será que é daqui que vem a expressão «partir a louça toda»??

Comment: @ANeves Era preciso saber se esses banquetes realmente existiram.

Answer (score 3):

[Fui procurar as primeiras ocorrências na literatura](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22MEIA-TIGELA%22&espv=2&biw=1587&bih=874&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A01%2F01%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1859&tbm=bks#tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:01%2F01%2F1800%2Ccd_max:31%2F12%2F1859&tbm=bks&q=%22meia+tigela%22), no google books.

Data de 1813, no mensário [Correio Braziliense ou Armazém Literário](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EFUPAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA335&dq=%22meia+tigela%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiForOPkvbQAhXMAsAKHes-B3wQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22meia%20tigela%22&f=false), publicado por Hipólito José da Costa Pereira Furtado de Mendonça é o primeiro a usar a expressao "de meia tigela". A expressão ocorre duas vezes, a primeira das quais na página 168

> ...e finalmente opprimio a soberba dos fidalgos **de meia tigela** desta
>   ilha, a cujos empenhos nao attendia

Já na outra ocorrencia, na página 335, a expressao "de meia tigela" também está associada a fidalgos

> ... que o Insulano (talves por espinha,) chama Fidalgos de meia tigela...

Segundo ainda os restantes livros da mesma pesquisa pode concluir-se que a expressão "de meia tigela", anda sempre associada a um ou mais indivíduos, ou a grupos sociais (tipicamente nobreza, daí o uso de fidalguia).

O primeiro livro a apresentar o uso da palavra associado a outras coisas data de 1886, intitulado de [Almanach de lembrancas Luso-Brazileiro](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_0JPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA126&dq=%22meia+tigela%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_KeorffQAhVDKMAKHRxoBF84ChDoAQgZMAA#v=onepage&q=%22meia%20tigela%22&f=false), aparece a dita expressão na seguinte frase:

> Era um d'aqueles bailes de meia tigela que tanto se usão em Paris

Comment: "Cabe aos outros usuários [...]". E cabe-te a ti dizer o que cabe aos outros, o isto é só uma maneira de dizeres que não tás para te chatear mais? :) Nas duas passagens, é *fidalgos de meia tigela*, mas uma limitação disto é que só com um exemplo não dá para ver se a expressão se aplicou primeiro a fidalgos ou a outra coisa qualquer. E como tu às vezes és um bocado apressado, será que isto é mesmo a primeira ocorrência do Google Books?

Comment: @Jacinto Foi uma forma genuina de dizer que a resposta nao está completa. Afinal de contas nao respondi á parte "saber quando é que se começa a ver a expressão usada fora do contexto original, isto é aplicada a outras personagens, como jornalistas ou políticos". Segundo a perquisa que fiz, e acabei de confirmar, os restantes livros sao datados depois deste. Poderás eventualmente ter outros resultados com uma pesquisa diferente, ou noutros motores de busca... sei lá... O problema é que para este tipo de perguntas qualquer fonte que uses vai acabar por ser sempre uma aproximacao.

Comment: @Jacinto Ainda assim, creio que vou dar algúm crédito creio que há uma forma simples de melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Acho importante ver várias das ocorrências mais antigas, para ver se a expressão é sempre aplicada a *fidalgo* ou a outras coisas também. Há [o dicionário do Bluteau, 1712-28](http://purl.pt/13969/4/) que talvez valha a pena consultar. E há por vezes nos resultados do Google uma Enciclopédia de 195? (aparece mesmo "195?") que por vezes traz citações de autores antigos, por vezes mais antigos que o mais antigo dos livros.

Comment: Vê *tijela* nos dicionários antigos, especialmente no Bluteau. Tenho no meta um post com [links aos dicionários](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/288/resources-for-etymological-research-recursos-para-investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-etimol%C3%B3gica?cb=1) (links mais práticos que o que incluí no comentário acima). Por vezes os dicionários trazem a palavra ou expressão antes de qualquer livro no Google; e podem trazer alguma coisa que elucide o significado, uso, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pequena contribuição. ***Fidalgo de meia-tigela*** já vem em 1721 no [*Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino* de Raphael Bluteau (volume da letra Q, pág. 163)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=oONBAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA163&dq=%22Fidalgo%20de%20meya%20tigela;%20aquelle%20que%20he%20meyo%20Fidalgo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3gviyiqDfAhV1OX0KHSCtAp0Q6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Fidalgo%20de%20meya%20tigela%3B%20aquelle%20que%20he%20meyo%20Fidalgo%22&f=false):

> **Tigêla**. Vaso concavo, em q de ordinario se põem sopas, doces, & outros mãjares. [traduções em latim com explicações].
>   Fidalgo de meya tigela; aquelle que he meyo Fidalgo. Fidalgo de quarto de tigela. Aquelle que ainda he menos Fidalgo, que o primeyro. São modos de fallar familiarmente.

A data impressa do volume é 1721. Se não me falha a memória, o p. Bluteau informa em passagem de cuja localização não me lembro que começou a compilar os materiais e verbetes em cadernos (ou já tinha compilado) em 1698.

Comment: Fernando! Seja bem vindo. Tu não está respondendo a pergunta, mas adicionando informações a resposta. Nesse caso, deve adicionar um comentário.

Comment: Fernando, obrigado pela "pequena contribuição". Vê o que eu fiz à tua resposta. Podes sempre alterar (é a tua resposta) clicando em "edit", canto inferior esquerdo. Basicamente Linkei ao Bluteau no Google Books, e pus a citação em bloco, mais uns ajustamentos menores.

Comment: Fernando, o porquê de "meia-tigela" continua obscuro, mas parece então que o termo se aplicou mesmo primeiro a fidalgos. Será que o "meio fidalgo" do Bluteau era mesmo uma designação com um significado definido, ou só uma maneira de Bluteau referir fidalgos de estatuto inferior?